# Is it possible to associate an arbitrary email address with an existing Google account for accessing a shared document?

Tags: google-workspace

I have a Google Docs file that I want to share with my co-workers. Some of us have Google accounts but we would prefer to share the file using our business emails.

However those who already have Google accounts, usually keep themselves logged in all day and constant switching is a bit of a pain.

Is there some way to associate an arbitrary email address with an **existing** Google account so that the latter can access Docs shared to the former?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Google Account with any e-mail address you want. And from account settings->edit e-email you can add any e-mail to your google account.

Comment: Any email address? I thought the address had to end with "@gmail.com"?